# Injection in Quartz Jobs (JSF + CDI)

Tags: jsf, quartz-scheduler, cdi

I want to send email on every Monday to remind my users of important events by reading from the database. I tested it with simple commands and the quartz jobs seems to be working fine. But when I try to inject my service into the Quartz job, it always return null.

I found some answers about this but none of them is helpful. Please help.

If it's not possible or too complicated, what other options do I have? e.g,. any other library?

I also followed this guide https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/scheduler.html but still can't get it to run properly.

FYI, I'm running JSF2 on Glassfish.

Comment: You are using a Java EE server. Use EJB timers instead, if they suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have it working now.